# Find number of vowels in a word

Tags: bash, grep

How can a find all the vowels for a word in bash?

```
grep -o "a"  <<<$1 | wc l
```

This command finds only `a`, and I want to find `aeiou`.

For example:

- for `car` I want the output to be `1`
- for `computer` I want the output to be `3`

Comment: I guess you're looking for a thing called "regular expressions" -- GNU grep supports them.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `-o` (only retain matches) with `wc -l` and use a bracket expression to match all vowels:

```
$ grep -o '[aeiou]' <<< car | wc -l
1
$ grep -o '[aeiou]' <<< computer | wc -l
3
```

As a function (notice quotes around `$1` to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion):

```
vowcount () { grep -o '[aeiou]' <<< "$1" | wc -l; }
```

Used like

```
$ vowcount alphabet
3
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
echo "computer" | awk '{print gsub(/[aeiou]/,"")}'
```

So I am using `echo` here to print the word, sending its standard output to `awk` by pipe (`|`) as standard input, then performing global substitution of letters `a`,`e`,`i`, `o`,`u` with the empty string (`""`).
Since `gsub` returns the count of substitutions performed, it tells us how many vowel letters are present in the string.

Answer (score 1):

***bash*** approach with GNU `expr` command:

Input variables:

```
v1="computer"
v2="car"
```

---

```
expr length "${v1//[^aeuoi]}"
3
```

---

```
expr length "${v2//[^aeuoi]}"
1
```

---

- `${v2//[^aeuoi]}` - replacing/removing all *non-vowel* characters
- `expr length STRING` - evaluates length of *STRING*

---

A more compatible variation would look like:

```
vowels="${v1//[^aeuoi]}"
echo "${#vowels}"
3
```